# RS485 PCB Design

Tags: pcb, uart, design, rs485

I'm currently in the process of designing PCBs for my project. There's going to be one larger control board, and 10 daughter boards. The daughter boards will measure the current/voltage of some lighting fixtures, and then send the data back to the master control board.

I wanted to implement communication between them with RS485. Last time I did it with SPI (at TTL level voltages), and I had a lot of interference, and inductive spiking, so I thought it would make sense to choose RS485 for the comms.

My question is, should I keep the power supplies of the smaller boards separate, and then opto-isolate them? Or can I keep the grounds between them connected? The control board will be quite large - 25x20cm, and there will be long tracks between everything.

Comment: Do the daughter boards plug directly onto the controller board, or is there a distance between them?

Comment: @SteveG, the boards interconnect directly

Comment: RS-485 isn't really designed for board-to-board connections, it's designed for long-distance communication. I recommend instead looking into where your SPI interference and inductive spiking is coming from and try to minimize and protect against that.

Comment: Okay, I will stick to regular TTL UART. How can I protect the IOs? I was thinking about some Schottky Diode clamping to both VCC and Ground, won't this interfere with my UART stream? Also I will add some filtering. Is the STM32's GPIO output current enough to drive such UART line, or do I need some external buffer/driver? Can I tri-state TTL UART with multiple slaves, I mean that is why I was planing to use RS485 anyways. Best Regards